# How do I store a data into the firebase database without updating it? and also retrieving the data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently working on a project that might be useful in a store for the ordering of foods. The device can already store some data and retrieve but there are problems that I have been dealing with.

**Problem 1#:** First off is that every time I store a data it usually looks like this:

[image]

For some reason I tried to use child "02" because it displays in the recycler view if I do something like "Ordering" as a child it does not seem to be showing in the display. How do I add more data to it like example in the child 02 I can still add like milkshakes or candy bars? This is the code I have done for storing.

```java
public class Detailsoforder extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "AddToDatabase";

    private TextView titles;
    private TextView increase;
    private int count = 0;

    //add Firebase
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailsoforder);

        titles = findViewById(R.id.Order);
        increase = findViewById(R.id.Increase);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");

        titles.setText(title);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
            }
        };

        // Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue();
                Log.d(TAG,"Value is"+value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void onIncreaseClick(View view) {

        count++;
        increase.setText(String.valueOf(count));

    }

    public void onOrderNow(View view) {

        String value = increase.getText().toString();

        if (value.equals("1")) {

            Toast.makeText(Detailsoforder.this,"The order must be above 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Attempting to add object to database.");
            String newFood = titles.getText().toString();
            if (!newFood.equals("")) {
                FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                String userID = user.getUid();
                myRef.child(userID).child("02").child("food").setValue(newFood);
                myRef.child(userID).child("02").child("order").setValue(value);
                Toast.makeText(Detailsoforder.this,"Adding " + newFood + " to database...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //reset the text
                titles.setText("");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Detailsoforder.this, Placeorder.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I store many data and not needing for updating it?

**Problem 2#:** Retrieving of the data. The problem is that I can only seem to get only 1 data. I wanted to fix the store part first so that I could check if I could get the many information. This is my code for retrieving of the data.

```
public class Vieworders extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView1;
private ViewHolder1 mAdapter1;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference1;
private List<Model1> mModel1;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vieworders);

    mRecyclerView1= findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    mRecyclerView1.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mModel1 = new ArrayList<>();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    String userID = user.getUid();
    mAdapter1=new ViewHolder1(Vieworders.this, mModel1);
    mRecyclerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter1);
    mDatabaseReference1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(userID);
    mDatabaseReference1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Model1 model1=postSnapshot.getValue(Model1.class);
                mModel1.add(model1);
            }
            mAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Vieworders.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Can someone help me, please? I really need this to be done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are able to send data to fire and able to store these datas.
   Now ,this is my snipshots of fetching data from Firebase .You can take help from this code.

```
 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<RoomRentData> firebaselist;
    private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    private DualProgressView progressView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_rent_activity);

        firebaselist=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rent_item);
        progressView=findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
        progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),1));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator( new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.hasFixedSize();

        final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        String year=Integer.toString(today.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        mFirebaseInstance = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = mFirebaseInstance.getReference("room_rent").child(year);

        mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                System.out.println("1");
                RoomRentData user = dataSnapshot.getValue(RoomRentData.class);

                if (user == null) {
                    System.out.println("2");
                    Toast.makeText(ShowRentActivity.this,"No data found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }else {
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 :dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        System.out.println("datasnapshot 1"+dataSnapshot1);
                        System.out.println("3");
                        RoomRentData userdetails = dataSnapshot1.getValue(RoomRentData.class);

                        System.out.println("userdetails 1"+userdetails);
                        RoomRentData listdata = new RoomRentData();
                        String month=userdetails.getMonth();
                        String year=userdetails.getYear();
                        String cuRead=userdetails.getCurrentRead();
                        String prevRead=userdetails.getPrevUnit();
                        String totalRent=userdetails.getTotalRoomRent();

                        String perPersonCost=userdetails.getPerpersonCost();
                        String totalPeron=userdetails.getTotalPerson();
                        String paidOn=userdetails.getCurrentTimeAndDate();
                        String description=userdetails.getDescription();

                        System.out.println("description 1"+description);
                        System.out.println("month"+month);

                        listdata.setMonth(month);
                        listdata.setYear(year);
                        listdata.setCurrentRead(cuRead);
                        listdata.setPrevUnit(prevRead);
                        listdata.setTotalRoomRent(totalRent);
                        listdata.setPerpersonCost(perPersonCost);
                        listdata.setTotalPerson(totalPeron);
                        listdata.setCurrentTimeAndDate(paidOn);
                        listdata.setDescription(description);


                        firebaselist.add(listdata);
                    }

                    rentAdapter firebaseListAdapter=new rentAdapter(getApplicationContext(),firebaselist);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                System.out.println(error);
                System.out.println("error");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have create a Model Class named **RoomRentData.class**.I have added this data to the RecyclerView using this model.

And This is my Model Class Code.

```
public class RoomRentData {

    private String month;
    private String year;
    private String roomRent;
    private String perUnitCost;
    private String PrevUnit;
    private String CurrentRead;
    private String totalUnitCostt;
    private String totalRoomRent;
    private String totalPerson;
    private String perpersonCost;
    private String description;
    private String currentTimeAndDate;

    public String getCurrentRead() {
        return CurrentRead;
    }

    public String getCurrentTimeAndDate() {
        return currentTimeAndDate;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public String getPerpersonCost() {
        return perpersonCost;
    }

    public String getPerUnitCost() {
        return perUnitCost;
    }

    public String getPrevUnit() {
        return PrevUnit;
    }

    public String getRoomRent() {
        return roomRent;
    }

    public String getTotalPerson() {
        return totalPerson;
    }

    public String getTotalRoomRent() {
        return totalRoomRent;
    }

    public String getTotalUnitCostt() {
        return totalUnitCostt;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setCurrentRead(String currentRead) {
        CurrentRead = currentRead;
    }

    public void setCurrentTimeAndDate(String currentTimeAndDate) {
        this.currentTimeAndDate = currentTimeAndDate;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public void setMonth(String month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    public void setPerpersonCost(String perpersonCost) {
        this.perpersonCost = perpersonCost;
    }

    public void setPerUnitCost(String perUnitCost) {
        this.perUnitCost = perUnitCost;
    }

    public void setPrevUnit(String prevUnit) {
        PrevUnit = prevUnit;
    }

    public void setRoomRent(String roomRent) {
        this.roomRent = roomRent;
    }

    public void setTotalPerson(String totalPerson) {
        this.totalPerson = totalPerson;
    }

    public void setTotalRoomRent(String totalRoomRent) {
        this.totalRoomRent = totalRoomRent;
    }

    public void setTotalUnitCostt(String totalUnitCostt) {
        this.totalUnitCostt = totalUnitCostt;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I was able to send dat but I dont want it to keep updating I want it to be able to get datas for everytime I store data

Comment: Oh nvm I already done it. I hope that this post will help someone in the futue. I just replace the private int click into private static int.